# Mudar cor do ícone Sidemenu

Tags: ionic

Boa tarde,  como faço para alterar a cor do ícone do sidemenu? Olhei a documentação e fiz algumas pesquisas mas não encontrei nada.

[image: img]

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar  class="navbar-amcham">
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title>AMCHAM RIO</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Qual framework vc está usando? Cade seu CSS, HTML, etc? Apenas com o que vc colocou na pergunta não da para saber ao que vc se refere, coloca pelo meno o link da documentação.

Comment: @hugocsl o framework é IONIC. Não é um um problema de HTML e CSS, a pergunta é sobre um ecossistema proprio.

Comment: posta as classes que estão declaradas na linha do side menu fazendo favor.

Comment: Apenas um projeto em branco criado como sidemenu no Ionic. Porém não sei onde encontro esse ícone no projeto.

Comment: @FelipeXST posta o html na pergunta junto então pra gente poder dar uma olhada

Comment: @SHRIMP editei o post e adicionei o codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que no SCSS global deva fazer algo como:

```
ion-header {
    ion-icon {
         color: #fc0; /*laranja*/
    }
}
```

No ionic 1 o arquivo a ser editado é o `./scss/ionic.app.scss` e no ionic3 é o `./src/app/app.scss`

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo variables.scss você define a cor:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #3e66ab,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #dd303e,
  light:      #edeff2,
  dark:       #333333
);
```

E na tag do ion-icon você atribui a cor:

```
<ion-icon name="menu" color="dark"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

dentro do projeto tem o arquivo `variables.scss` onde você vai setar todas as cores do seu código.

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  suaCor: #b13371
);
```

Ja existem algumas default, mas é só adicionar uma nova como no exemplo acima em `suaCor`.

Depois de setar a cor no arquivo `.sass` você apenas vai chama-la como no exemplo abaixo

```
<button ion-button menuToggle color="suaCor">
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Sua solução funcionou também.

Comment: procure sempre setar as cores dentro desse arquivo global para uma melhor otimização depois! e fico feliz de ter ajudado :D